# Installing cx_freeze via msys2

Tags: python, pip, msys2

I am trying to write a small gtk application with Python.

I was told that you should use msys2 for MS-Windows. See related question: [Setting up developement environment: PyCharm, python-gtk, windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787630/setting-up-developement-environment-pycharm-python-gtk-windows)

Now I need cx_freeze. There are wheel-files for windows, but I guess the msys2 environment is different, and that's why installing "cx_freeze" fails (no gcc around).

See files of cx_freeze: https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/#files

Now I am unsure if I am on the right track.

Is there a way to use the ready build wheels from a python which is started in msys2 (In my case `C:\msys32\usr\bin\python3.exe`)

Installing cx_freeze worked after installing gcc. But now I get this error:

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console
```

I guess I should not compile cx_freeze and get my environment use the provided wheels.

**Update**

I leave this question open, because someone else could find a solution and help someone else again. But I switched from gtk to pyside2 (QT). Everything is much easier now.